# Task fired again after WaitAll

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task

Using `HttpClient.GetAsync` or any of its async method, or any BCL async method in Linq `Select` might result in some strange twice shoot.

Here a unit test case:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestTwiceShoot()
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    items.Add("1");
    int k = 0;

    var tasks = items.Select(d =>
    {
        k++;
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        return client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://testdevserver.ibs.local:8020/prestashop/api/products/1"));
    });

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    foreach (var r in tasks)
    {

    }

    Assert.AreEqual(1, k);           
}
```

The test will fail, since k is 2. Somehow the program run the delegate of firing `GetAsync` twice. Why?

If I remove `foreach (var r in tasks)`, the test pass. Why?

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestTwiceShoot()
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    items.Add("1");
    int k = 0;

    var tasks = items.Select(d =>
    {
        k++;
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        return client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://testdevserver.ibs.local:8020/prestashop/api/products/1"));
    });

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    Assert.AreEqual(1, k);

}
```

If I use `foreach` instead of `items.Select`, the test pass.  Why?

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestTwiceShoot()
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    items.Add("1");
    int k = 0;

    var tasks = new List<Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>>();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        k++;
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        tasks.Add( client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://testdevserver.ibs.local:8020/prestashop/api/products/1")));
    };

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    foreach (var r in tasks)
    {

    }

    Assert.AreEqual(1, k);

}
```

Apparently the enumerator returned by `items.Select` is not living well with the `Task` object returned, as soon as I walk the enumerator, the delegate got fired again.

This test pass.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestTwiceShoot()
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    items.Add("1");
    int k = 0;

    var tasks = items.Select(d =>
    {
        k++;
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        return client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://testdevserver.ibs.local:8020/prestashop/api/products/1"));

    });


    var tasksArray = tasks.ToArray();
    Task.WaitAll(tasksArray);

    foreach (var r in tasksArray)
    {

    }

    Assert.AreEqual(1, k);

}
```

Scott mentioned that the `Select` may run again when walking the enumerator, however, this test pass

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestTwiceShoot()
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    items.Add("1");
    int k = 0;

    var tasks = items.Select(d =>
    {
        k++;
        return int.Parse(d);

    });

    foreach (var r in tasks)
    {

    };

    Assert.AreEqual(1, k);

}
```

I guess the Linq `Select` has some special treatment against `Task`.

After all, what's the good way of firing multiple async method in Linq and the examine the results after `WaitAll`?

Comment: You're not calling `items.ToArray()` to materialise the collection in your test method, so the iteration only happens once (via `foreach`). Scott's answer is correct, your test is not.

Comment: Your first test (using tasks) is also not representative of your actual code, because in the test you're iterating over the array produced by `tasks.ToArray()` (therefore the actual `tasks` enumerable is only iterated through once - via the call to `.ToArray()`), whereas in the original code sample you iterate over `tasks` first via a call to `.ToArray()`, and subsequently via a `foreach` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `tasks` is `IEnumerable<Task>` and each time you enumerate through the list it will re-run the `.Select()` operation. Currently you run through the list twice, one when you call `.ToArray()` and once when you pass it in to the `foreach`

To fix the problem just use the `.ToArray()` like you are but move it earlier up.

```
    var tasks = items.Select(d =>
    {
        k++;
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        return client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://testdevserver.ibs.local:8020/prestashop/api/products/1"));

    }).ToArray(); //This makes tasks a "Task[]" instead of a IEnumerable<Task>.

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    foreach (var r in tasks)
    {

    };
```

Things like what happened to you is why Microsoft reccomends that when you write Linq statements that they do not have any side effects (like incrementing `k`) because it is hard to tell how many times the statement will be run, especially if the resultant `IEnumerable<T>` goes out of your scope of control by being returned as a result or passed in to a new function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is my misconception about how enumeration works. These tests pass:

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void TestTwiceShoot()
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        items.Add("1");
        int k = 0;

        var tasks = items.Select(d =>
        {
            k++;
            return int.Parse(d);

        });

        foreach (var r in tasks)
        {

        };

        foreach (var r in tasks)
        {

        };

        Assert.AreEqual(2, k);

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestTwiceShoot2()
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        items.Add("1");
        int k = 0;

        var tasks = items.Where(d =>
        {
            k++;
            return true;

        });

        foreach (var r in tasks)
        {

        };

        foreach (var r in tasks)
        {

        };

        Assert.AreEqual(2, k);

    }
```

I had though the Linq statement returns an IEnumerable object which store the results of the delegate. However, obviously it stores only the shortcuts to the delegates, so each enumerator walk will trigger the delegate. Therefore, it is good to use ToArray() or ToList() to get a list of results, like this one:

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void TestTwiceShoot2()
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        items.Add("1");
        int k = 0;

        var tasks = items.Where(d =>
        {
            k++;
            return true;

        }).ToList();

        foreach (var r in tasks)
        {

        };

        foreach (var r in tasks)
        {

        };

        Assert.AreEqual(1, k);

    }
```